# Automatically reload properties file after change

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream, file-properties

I'm developing an application which gets informations from a file properties and I create a field which puts new values into properties file
The problem is that when I submit changes, the file is not reloaded and changes are not considered only after reloading the application.
I'm working with Eclipse Indigo, Liferay 6.1, Tomcat 7.0, Vaadin, Spring, Hibernate and Maven

I'm using this class to save new values from the textField into the file

```
public class configurationProperties {

Properties prop = new Properties() ;
File fProp = new File("C:/integrationContinue/src/main/resources/fooMessages_fr_FR.properties") ;
FileInputStream stream = null;
FileOutputStream oStream = null;

public void changeUrlJenkins(String url) throws IOException{


    stream = new FileInputStream(fProp);
    prop.load(stream) ;
    prop.setProperty("jenkins.url",url) ;
    oStream = new FileOutputStream(fProp);
    prop.store(oStream,"test") ;

}
```

When I click on save button nothing happens but if I open properties file

I get this message 
"The file '.../fooMessages_fr_FR.properties' has been changed on the file system. Do you want to replace the editor contents with these changes?"

When I click on "reload button" changes are submitted and application is reloaded => it's fine when I'm on eclipse, I can't do that on a web browser.

PS: I heard that it can work if I use Tomcat Manager instead of Tomcat integrated on Liferay, but when I wanted to configure Liferay with a new path for Tomcat errors appears

What can I do to automatically reload properties file after modify it

Answer (score 0):

You change the properties in a `src`-folder, that is wrong, you must change it in `classes`-folder.

ps: and this work with eclipse, because eclipse copied this to classes folder.

Comment: I replaced "C:/integrationContinue/src/main/resources/fooMessages_fr_FR.properties" with "/integrationContinue/target/classes/fooMessages_fr_FR.properties" It saves data in the file but it can't be open with eclipse and can't be reloaded because functions gets properties from resources folder and /target/classes appears only after "clean install"

Comment: I found solution on other topic it's only about closing FileInputStream and it works :)

Comment: But, I think it will be work with this solution and 'src' folder, only by running in eclipse. Because in "production" enviroment you will not have 'src'-folder.

Comment: I would prefer to find the file path with MyClass.getResource("myPackage/fooMessages_fr_FR.properties"); method. And then load it with new File(...);

Comment: I don't know how modifying my code to use properties in this way

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a deployment problem rather than tomcat not reading the properties correctly.

When you deploy to Tomcat through Eclipse, it copies the files from your project into the deployment directory, [eclipse workspace]/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/[server]. It may also copy it to the output directory, depending upon what you've configured.

So if understand correctly, youre saving to your workspace file /src/main/resources/fooMessages_fr_FR.properties? Eclipse doesn't realise that this file has been updated until you click on it, at which point it copies it to .plugins/blah, and everything works correctly.

This will probably work correctly if you deploy outside Eclipse, because there won't be any copying from your workspace to the deployment directory.

If you're still stuck after this, have a look at apache commons [FileChangedReloadingStrategy](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/reloading/FileChangedReloadingStrategy.html), which allows you to reload a properties file when it gets changed.